# Height of nested Xamarin ListViews

Tags: listview, xamarin

I am working on a Xamarin project with nested ListViews and I am searching an easy way to define the height of the ListViews in the Grid.

Currently I am trying it on three different ways:

1. When I am using  the height is way to large.
2. When I am using , where SubItemsListHeightWithFixHeightPerItem is number of items times a static integer, the height is sometimes correct, but only for a specific content (If I would show multi line text or images, it would no longer work).
3. When I am using , where SubItemsListHeight is the height of the Frames inside the ListView, which is taken from the SizeChanged event, the as text shown height seems plausible but does not apply on the RowDefinition.

I created a small Example application at https://github.com/hobber89/xamarinListViewSizingExample.

I would be very thankful if anyone can tell me a simple way to define an accurate definition and binding of the height of the rows!

Kind regards,
hobber89

Comment: The third method you use is the right way to bind the height to the row.

Comment: I added buttons to test if binding on RowDefinition.Height works and detected it can not be bound do double but to GridLength (updated in the Git Repository). Thus, I added a NumberToGridLength Converter. But on https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4609 I read: "RowDefinitions are not inheriting the BindingContext." Does anyone know an example with a working example for bind that value? After the change the height of the row is way too high.

Comment: You can use the path to bind the data to the Row like this `<RowDefinition Height="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=itemsListView}, Path=BindingContext.SmallImageHeight}" />`.